# Neural Machine Translation

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

I am doing a project about Neural Machine Translation. In the data processing step, is it necessary to padding after the sentences so that they are of equal length?

Comment: How can you specify the dimensions of the input to your model if they aren't all guaranteed to be the same size?

Comment: I will padding the zeros after the sentences so they all have a given length